# Best way to migrate and regenerate Symfony 3 entities

Tags: symfony, migration

I am learning Symfony 3 and would like to know what is the best way to create a migration and then regenerate an entity based on the schema that has changed in the database migration.

At the moment, what I have done is this:
Install this bundle:

```
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0"
```

Changed the fields in my `doctrine.orm.yml` file

In the windows command line, I wrote:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

Then

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

This successfully created a migration with a new table called "migration-versions" and a new entity with the same name.

My problem now is that the entity that has changed still has the old data, I would like the new migration to update this specific entity, and here I am stuck.

Shall I delete it manually and type in the command line?

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you created entities for your tables?

Comment: As I understood you don't want to lose data.  Actually, you have to improve your migration in such way that it will do what you need and keep the way to rollback it in a case of emergency. If you describe what kind of changes you have, I will try to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all the migrations only affect your database. The `migrations_versions` is the internal table where Symfony store information, you don't need to bother about this table.

The workflow of migrations is like this:

1. You change your mapping (the EntityName.orm.yml)
2. Run `doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:EntityName` (this will create your entity with the new fields).
3. Run `doctrine:migrations:diff` (this will automatically check the differences and will create a migration that will affect your DB)
4. Run `doctrine:migrations:migrate` to persist the changes to the DB.

Your generated entities with the `doctrine:generate:entities` has nothing to do with the migration concept (it's just a mapping for the db table with php object).

When you generate the entities Symfony detect new fields (from EntityName.orm.yml) and attach the setters/getters for them in the Entity class. Simfony doesn't delete old stuff from the Entity class because you can add your own logic there and you don't want it to be deleted after a command run. If you want to delete them just do it manually, or if you didn't add any logic in there you can just delete the file and rerun `doctrine:generate:entities`.

Hope it helps!